# iphone; UTF strings from xml

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unicode

Hi there 
I have been trying to read an xml file with UTF strings, and am stuck with trying to convert them. My scenario

1. Reading xml file from the internet - at times, the xml file contains unicode
2. The files read ok, displays ok in the browser
3. But when i try to display them - instead of the unicode characters i see ascii converted, something like & #54620;& #54620; [ i added space so that it does'nt display UTF in the post ]
4. I tried to ocnvert them into UTF8String using [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[description UTF8String]], but did'nt work

What am i missing here?

edit: If i can understand how to convert a string & #2310;& #2306;& #2358;& #2367;& #2325; & #2313; (ofcourse without the spaces after the &) into its respective UTF symbols (in this case - hindi) - it would be a good start

edit: Sample xml content
description="`&#2326; &#2340;`" which i would like to convert to UTF characters, i could not find any function to do this conversion

Thanks

Comment: veeru, do those UTF-8 characters you've included really have spaces between & and #?

Comment: nope, NO spaces, i added spaces in this post so that it does'nt display the UTF character

Comment: am kinda stuck on this one? anybody ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you're reading that XML into an NSData object; it looks like you're converting it to a string somewhere, in description. Try this approach:

```
NSData *response = [self getXMLData];
NSString *content = [[NSString alloc]  initWithBytes:[response bytes]
   length:[response length] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

that should get you a good string with properly formed characters.

Comment: am using TBXML, i have tried what you suggested, the nslog of content shows the unicode parts as & #54620; etc; but when i tried to display it using something like this NSString *description=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"description" forElement:city]];lblCurrentConditionText.text= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[description UTF8String]]; -- it still shows & #54620;

Comment: what if before you assign description, you just created a string with NSString *preString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"description" forElement:city]];

Comment: NSString *description=[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"description" forElement:city];
  const char* utfStr = [description UTF8String];
  NSLog(@"Description >>%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:utfStr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
I tried the above too, i still see only the asii version